Не отображает картинку Django
#HTML
<div class="container-promo">
    {% for obj in promo_objects %}
    <img src="{{ promos.img.url }}" class="promo" />
    {% endfor %}
</div>

#Корневой urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('dj-admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('customadmin.urls')),
    path('', include('main.urls')),
]
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

#models.py
class Promos(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    img = models.ImageField('Изображение', upload_to='promos/')

#views.py
def promo(request):
    promo_objects = Promos.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'main/promo.html', {'promo_objects': promo_objects})

#settings.py
MEDIA_ROOT = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media'))
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'


Библиотека pillow установлена.
В терминале "GET /promo HTTP/1.1" 200 15393
путь изображений media => promos
Выводит:


Как обычно проблема кроется в самом простом, вместо {{promos.img.url}} (я указывал класс), надо указать перечисляемый объект в цикле {{ obj.img.url}}
